# How to fix errors in my DB?

Tags: php, database, windows, mamp, local

I created my WP website locally and I am in the process of migration to the server. Trying to export the database, I got a message saying some errors have been detected as follow:

---

```
Warning in .\libraries\plugin_interface.lib.php#551
 count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
Backtrace
.\libraries\display_export.lib.php#384: PMA_pluginGetOptions(
string 'Export',
array,
)
.\libraries\display_export.lib.php#882: PMA_getHtmlForExportOptionsFormat(array)
.\libraries\display_export.lib.php#1096: PMA_getHtmlForExportOptions(
string 'database',
string 'srathnam',
string '',
string '<div class="export_table_list_container"><input type="hidden" name="structure_or_data_forced" value="0"><table class="export_table_select"><thead><tr><th></th><th>Tables</th><th class="export_structure">Structure</th><th class="export_data">Data</th></tr><tr><td></td><td class="export_table_name all">Select all</td><td class="export_structure all"><input type="checkbox" id="table_structure_all" /></td><td class="export_data all"><input type="checkbox" id="table_data_all" /></td></tr></thead><tbody> <tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_commentmeta" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_commentmeta</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_commentmeta" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_commentmeta" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_comments" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_comments</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_comments" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_comments" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_duplicator_packages" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_duplicator_packages</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_duplicator_packages" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_duplicator_packages" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_links" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_links</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_links" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_links" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_options" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_options</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_options" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_options" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_postmeta" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_postmeta</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_postmeta" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_postmeta" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_posts" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_posts</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_posts" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_posts" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_tcb_api_error_log" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_tcb_api_error_log</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_tcb_api_error_log" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_tcb_api_error_log" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_termmeta" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_termmeta</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_termmeta" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_termmeta" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_terms" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_terms</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_terms" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_terms" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_term_relationships" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_term_relationships</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_term_relationships" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_term_relationships" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_term_taxonomy" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_term_taxonomy</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_term_taxonomy" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_term_taxonomy" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_usermeta" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_usermeta</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_usermeta" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_usermeta" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_users" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_users</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_users" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_users" checked="checked" /></td></tr> </tbody></table></div>',
integer 14,
array,
integer 0,
)
.\db_export.php#154: PMA_getExportDisplay(
string 'database',
string 'srathnam',
string '',
string '',
integer 14,
integer 0,
string '<div class="export_table_list_container"><input type="hidden" name="structure_or_data_forced" value="0"><table class="export_table_select"><thead><tr><th></th><th>Tables</th><th class="export_structure">Structure</th><th class="export_data">Data</th></tr><tr><td></td><td class="export_table_name all">Select all</td><td class="export_structure all"><input type="checkbox" id="table_structure_all" /></td><td class="export_data all"><input type="checkbox" id="table_data_all" /></td></tr></thead><tbody> <tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_commentmeta" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_commentmeta</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_commentmeta" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_commentmeta" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_comments" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_comments</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_comments" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_comments" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_duplicator_packages" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_duplicator_packages</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_duplicator_packages" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_duplicator_packages" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_links" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_links</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_links" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_links" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_options" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_options</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_options" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_options" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_postmeta" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_postmeta</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_postmeta" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_postmeta" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_posts" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_posts</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_posts" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_posts" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_tcb_api_error_log" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_tcb_api_error_log</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_tcb_api_error_log" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_tcb_api_error_log" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_termmeta" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_termmeta</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_termmeta" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_termmeta" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_terms" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_terms</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_terms" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_terms" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_term_relationships" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_term_relationships</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_term_relationships" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_term_relationships" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_term_taxonomy" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_term_taxonomy</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_term_taxonomy" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_term_taxonomy" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_usermeta" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_usermeta</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_usermeta" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_usermeta" checked="checked" /></td></tr><tr class="marked"><td><input type="checkbox" name="table_select[]" value="wp_users" checked="checked" class="checkall"/></td><td class="export_table_name">wp_users</td><td class="export_structure"><input type="checkbox" name="table_structure[]" value="wp_users" checked="checked" /></td><td class="export_data"><input type="checkbox" name="table_data[]" value="wp_users" checked="checked" /></td></tr> </tbody></table></div>',
)
```

Any  idea why I have such a message? What is the mistake I did? How impacting is it? And how to solve it?

Comment: How did you export it exactly? In phpmyadmin, you simply have the option to click export and get the file as a .sql file, then use your webhosts phpadmin panel to import the database there.

Comment: Get a new plugin?  I just export for PHPmyAdmin, then change the site_url and blog_url in wp_options table, and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Martin, I clicked on the Export tab from phpMyAdmin dashboard of my MAMP installation and got this pop-up signaling some errors have been detected on the server. I can ignore it and keep further in the process but I want to make sure to manage this properly as I don't have any knowledge in this field. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of PHPMyadmin?

Comment: The PHPMyadmin version is the one linked to MAMP software. It is Version: 4.7.0